# Vue Data Table Headers All Appearing in One Column

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have a `v-data-table` and I am trying to print my headings, but with my code they are all appearing grouped into one column instead of across the entire table.

```
<template v-slot:header>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <div v-for="(itm, i) in hdrs" :key="i">
              <th>
                {{itm.value}}
              </th>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</template>
```

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to how to resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the loop should be done in the `th` elements and remove the div one :

```
<tr>
  <tempalte v-for="(itm, i) in hdrs">
     <th v-if="someCondition">
      {{itm.value}}
     </th>
  </template>
</tr>
```

Comment: Agreed - but what if I don't want to display the `<th> </th>` on certain headings?  Doing it this way produces large gaps in the `v-data-table`?

Comment: you could use conditional rendering using `v-if`

Comment: Doesn't that have to go inside the `<th>` tags in this case?  Which means it will always attempt to render the column header, but not print the contents.

Comment: the v-for loop could be done in a virtual element `template` and the v-if done in the th element which will  be rendered based on the condition

Comment: This still creates a blank `<th> </th>` element?

Comment: D'oh you're right!  I have my logic muddled, sorry.